# Excel date formatting after formula calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Say I have the following two dates in column 1 of my spreadsheet:

```
Tuesday, February 12, 2013 10:13 AM
2/12/2013 10:13
```

When I highlight the column and change the cell formatting to a date type of "3/14/12 1:30 PM" it changes row 2 but not row 1.  I quickly discovered that removing "Tuesday, " fixed the issue.  In other words, it will properly format "February 12, 2012 10:13 AM" but **not** "Tuesday, February 12, 2013 10:13 AM".

From there, I started writing a simple formula to remedy the situation.  I created a second column and set the formula to

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"Tuesday, ","")
```

This created the following contents:

```
February 12, 2013 10:13 AM
41317.4256944444
```

No matter how I reformat the cells it doesn't change the visible values.  Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The results of the `SUBSTITUTE` function are always text values so try adding +0 to the end of the formula to "co-erce" to a date value (and better to refer to a single cell rather than A:A), so in B2 try

`=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"Tuesday, ","")+0`

or to cope with any day of week try

`=IF(ISNUMBER(A2+0),A2,TRIM(REPLACE(A2,1,FIND(",",A2),"")))+0`

then format in required date/time format